# close dropdown menu on click outside

Tags: javascript

I've got this problem that my dropdown menu doesn't close on click outside, it seems that main cause of this problem is the Fontawesome user icon itself, I tried to find the problem with alert(), but the alert() activated on every single px of the website even when i clicked on the user icon itself.

```js
function dropdown() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
  x.classList.toggle("show");
}

var submenu = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#superior')) {
    if (submenu.classList.contains('show')) {
      submenu.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing : * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  }
  header {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  .navbar {
    min-height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 5px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 40px;
    gap: 50px;
  }
  .nav-branding {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-item {
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  .nav-link {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .submenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 295px;
    transform: translateX(-79%);
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
  }
  .sub-link {
    color: white;
  }
  .show {
    display: block;
  }
  border-box;
  font-family: 'Raleway',
  sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #fff;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 40px;
  gap: 50px;
}

.nav-branding {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.nav-link {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 295px;
  transform: translateX(-79%);
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.sub-link {
  color: white;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6b8781539d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item user-menu">
        <a onclick="dropdown()" id="superior" href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></a>
        <ul id="submenu" class="submenu">
          <li>
            <a class="sub-link" href="#">link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="sub-link" href="#">link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="sub-link" href="#">link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="sub-link" href="#">link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add code snippet correctly

Answer (score 0):

Detect click and check the closest parent of clicked element. Yes now it's supported without jQuery.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  var elem = event.target;
  var closest = elem.closest(".jmp-container");
  if (closest) {

    // console.log("click inside")
  } else {

    // hide menu
    document.querySelector(".jmp-container")?.remove();



  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container,
.jmp-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  I AM REST OF BODY


  <div class="jmp-container">
    I AM NAVBAR
    <button>hello</button>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: well, thats what i'm trying to fix, i need the user icon to "function properly" because when i click on it its detected the same way as the rest of site (it says with alert() that i clicked outside even though i clicked on the one element that shouldn't be triggered by this script

Comment: can you demonstrate that in live snippet? (ctrl+m when editing)

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code with some simple adjustments, beggining with the CSS:

```css
.submenu{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 295px;
    transform: translateX(-79%);
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

I removed the `display: none` from the `.submenu` class and isolated it in a class called "hide", then hidding and displaying will be decoupled from the `submenu` class.

Now we need to adjust the javascript:

```js
function dropdown() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu")[0];
    x.classList.toggle("show");
    x.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

The `getElementsByClassName` returns a list, then we need to grab one element from the list instead of working with the entire list like you did.

After this, I just toggle the `show` and `hide` classes.

Now you just need to add the hide class to the HTML:

```html
<ul id="submenu" class="submenu hide">
    <li>
        <a class="sub-link" href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="sub-link" href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="sub-link" href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="sub-link" href="#">link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

In the end, your entire code will be:

JS:

```js
function dropdown() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu")[0];
    x.classList.toggle("show");
    x.classList.toggle("hide");
}

var submenu = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('#superior')) {
        if (submenu.classList.contains('show')) {
            submenu.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
}

var submenu = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('#superior')) {
        if (submenu.classList.contains('show')) {
            submenu.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: #fff;
}
/* foo */
li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.navbar {
    min-height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 40px;
    gap: 50px;
}

.nav-branding {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-item {
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.nav-link {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 295px;
    transform: translateX(-79%);
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.sub-link {
    color: white;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

header {
    background-color: #fff;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.navbar {
    min-height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 40px;
    gap: 50px;
}

.nav-branding {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-item {
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.nav-link {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.sub-link {
    color: white;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6b8781539d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <p href="#" class="nav-link">link 1</p>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item user-menu">
            <p onclick="dropdown()" id="superior" href="#" class="nav-link">foo</p>
            <ul id="submenu" class="submenu hide">
                <li>
                    <p class="sub-link" href="#">link 2</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p class="sub-link" href="#">link 3</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p class="sub-link" href="#">link 4</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p class="sub-link" href="#">link 5</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only css:

```css
.toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle:hover + .submenu, .submenu:hover {
    display: block;
}

.submenu {
    display: none;
    background-color: #efcdb3;
}
```

```html
<p class="toggle">Click</p>
<div class="submenu">
    <p>Hi</p>
</p>
```

**Edit**:

I just added `:hover` pseudo class in both toggle and the dropdown. When you put your cursor on the toggle, it will show the dropdown, and still also as the dropdown is in hover.

Hope it helps :D