# Javascript, how to close mobile navigation menu when pressed anywhere

Tags: javascript, mobile

Trying to get my mobile nav to close when user taps on screen. Currently can only close when user taps or clicks on "burger" icon, but this isn't native to many users. I would like the menu to close when to user taps or clicks eslewhere on the screen. Should be easy fix? I've been struggling with javascript and learning much through stackoverflow and MDN docs, but this solution eludes me.

This is the current code:

```
 // media query nav etc
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    
    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    

    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = '';
        } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 1.5}s`;
        }
    });
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
});

}
```

Comment: you mean everywhere other than the hamburger menu itself? this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74018222/3807365) might help

Comment: I'd like to keep the burger as viable, but specifically I'd like to activate the 'toggle 'to hide the drop-down menu if the user touches another part of the screen (the main items). And, if it can be done, to have the 'toggle' activated to disappear a second after a link has been clicked. I know almost enough javascript to get me into trouble, but "addEventListener" I know of is 'click'

Comment: I was able to add some javascript so the menu drop-down now disappears after a li is clicked.
****
const closeNav = () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  }
  navLinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', closeNav));
}
****
added after 
****
`burger.classList.toggle('toggle'); });****

still no solution to make drop-down disappear if *any part of the page is 'clicked'.